# Disabling Nagle algorithm in Kestrel Web Server of ASP.Net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

[KestrelServerOptions.NoDelay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.kestrelserveroptions.nodelay?view=aspnetcore-1.1) is not available in .NET Core 2.2 any more.

Please how can I disable Nagle algorithm in  Kestrel Web Server of ASP.Net Core 2.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling Nagle's algorithm is now available at [ListenOptions.NoDelay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.listenoptions.nodelay?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Here is the code snippet for the same

```
.ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
{
    options.Limits.MaxConcurrentConnections = 100;
    options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000, (listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.NoDelay = false;
    }));
});
```

Comment: How to do this for ASP Core 3.0? 

Answer (score 0):

listenOptions.NoDelay = false; Means enable Nagle algorithm.
Set to false to enable Nagle's algorithm for all connections.
Defaults to true.

Answer (score 0):

I can't post a comment, but wanted to share this as I couldn't find the answer until I went through the commit history for ListenOptions.cs [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/commit/ab52a1d3ed3fe6e62caa4bb9144f0a6f9d2c3225#diff-9ca3162cf80d50aaaa27525a7d72dc6a). For .Net Core 3.0/3.1, "NoDelay" has moved to SocketTransportOptions.

Example:

```
var builder = new WebHostBuilder().UseKestrel(kestrelServerOptions => {...}).UseSockets(socketTransportOptions => { socketTransportOptions.NoDelay = false; }).Build();
```

Comment: yep, I submitted that feature request to Microsoft, and they added it.